# dustjs html escape output from dusthelper

Tags: dust.js

I want to html escape the content from @pre. Output from {@pre key="property-key" type="content"/} is **this contains " and ' in sentence**. I want this to be escaped as **this contains & #34; and & #39; in sentence**.

I tried {@pre key="property-key" type="content" filters="h"/} but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Because `{@pre}` (I assume [this one](https://github.com/krakenjs/dust-message-helper/blob/master/index.js)) returns a Chunk, you can't directly modify the output.

You could wrap this helper in your own helper that HTML-escapes the return value.

```
dust.helpers.escapePre = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  return chunk.tap(function(data) {
    return dust.escapeHtml(data);
  }).helper('pre', context, bodies, params);
}

{@escapePre key="property-key" type="content" /}
```

This example helper just invokes the `pre` helper, and taps the output through a function that escapes all data passed to it.